# Build a Mastermind engine

Tags: code-golf

For reference to the game of Mastermind: [Solving Mastermind in 6 or less moves](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/5226/solving-mastermind-in-6-or-less-moves)

In the version of Mastermind used in this problem, the operating string is a 4-digit number, from 0000 to 9999, represented as either numbers from `0` to `9999` or strings of consecutive digits `"0000"` to `"9999"` in input.

Your task is to build a function that will take two numbers/strings `secret` and `guess` as input, and return two numbers `A` and `B`, the number of red and white pegs respectively.

The shortest code in any language to do this wins.

Comment: I think this spec would be improved by not having people go read the actual specification of the game in another challenge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## J: <strike>40</strike> <strike>26</strike> <strike>29</strike> 22

```
=,&(+/)(~:#[)e.&~.~:#]
```

- *change*: don't laminate, but work truly dyadically, eliminating need for explicit ranks ("1), lamination(,:) and between (/)
- *change*: don't count duplicate characters twice
- *change*: Strings are more efficient as they don't need parsing

This verb takes a left and right argument a string from '0000' to '9999'.
It takes care of doubles and excludes exact matches from checking correct numbers but wrong place.

Test cases:

```
NB. Give the beast a name
mm=: =,&(+/)(~:#[)e.&~.~:#]
NB. make 6 by 4 arrays of the inputs
secret =: (, ;. _2) '1254 1234 5441 5441 5441 5441 '
guess  =: (, ;. _2) '1342 1111 1234 4531 4441 5441 '

NB. Apply the verb on each pair of secret/guess
'1111' mm '1231'
2 0

NB. A whole bunch of test cases with formatting and printing of the inputs:
secret ([,' ',(":@mm),' ',])"1 guess

NB. output:
1254 1 2 1342
1234 1 0 1111
5441 0 2 1234
5441 1 2 4531
5441 3 0 4441
5441 4 0 5441
```

A little bit of explanation, reading from right to left:

```
NB.   ExactMatch: checks where digits correspond:
ExactMatch =: =

NB.   GoodDigitWrongPlace: Copies non-matched numbers from both arguments (left and right
NB.   pairs of parentheses, and checks them for same elements(e.), after eliminating
NB.   doubles in both (&~.)
GoodDigitWrongPlace =: (~: # [) (e.&~.) (~: # ])

NB.   Piecing the conditions together, after summing the booleans:
mm =: ExactMatch ,&(+/) GoodDigitWrongPlace
```

Comment: I think the result of "5441" and "1234" should be 0,2 rather than 0,3. The duplicate 4's should only be counted once. Save for "5441","4531"

Comment: Thanks, you are entirely right. Adds 3 characters `~.@`

Answer (score 4):

## K, <s>41</s> 36

```
{+/'(b;(in).(?x;y)@\:(!#x)@&~b:x=y)}
```

.

```
k)c1:("1254";"1234";"5441";"5441";"5441";"5441")
k)c2:("1342";"1111";"1234";"4531";"4441";"5441")
k){+/'(b;(in).(?x;y)@\:(!#x)@&~b:x=y)}'[c1;c2]
1 2
1 0
0 2
1 2
3 0
4 0
```

Answer (score 2):

### Ruby 2.0, 71 characters

```ruby
f=->s,g{[x=(0..3).count{|n|s[n]==g[n]},g.chars.count{|e|s.sub!e,''}-x]}
```

This function actually modifies the first parameter, which is obviously a bit dodgy.  Would be easy enough to fix if it's actually against the rules.

I'm sure there's something sneaky you could do with `String#count` but I couldn't think of a nice way to handle duplicates.

Example usage:

```
p f['1254', '1342'] #=> [1, 2]
p f['1234', '1111'] #=> [1, 0]
p f['5441', '1234'] #=> [0, 2]
p f['5441', '4531'] #=> [1, 2]
p f['5441', '4441'] #=> [3, 0]
p f['5441', '5441'] #=> [4, 0]
```

Comment: Modifying the parameters is fine (they're being passed by value, not by reference).

Comment: @JoeZ. Why is this the accepted answer, when there are at least three other answers that are shorter?

Comment: It was just one of the first to be posted.  I'm sure he'll update it next time he checks :>

Comment: @chron: Yup. `  `

Answer (score 1):

#### GolfScript, 50 characters

```
{[[\].zip{1/~=},,\{$}/{1$?.)!!{)>0}*)},,\;1$-]}:M;
```

A similar solution to [chron's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12490) written in GolfScript. Input must be provided as two strings on the stack, the result will be the array `[A B]`.

[Examples](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e1tbXF0uemlwezEvfj19LCxceyR9L3sxJD8uKSEheyk%2BMH0qKX0sLFw7MSQtXX06TTsKCiIxMjU0IiAiMTM0MiIgTSBwICAgICMgPT4gWzEgMl0KIjEyMzQiICIxMTExIiBNIHAgICAgIyA9PiBbMSAwXQoiNTQ0MSIgIjEyMzQiIE0gcCAgICAjID0%2BIFswIDJdCiI1NDQxIiAiNDUzMSIgTSBwICAgICMgPT4gWzEgMl0KIjU0NDEiICI0NDQxIiBNIHAgICAgIyA9PiBbMyAwXQoiNTQ0MSIgIjU0NDEiIE0gcCAgICAjID0%2BIFs0IDBdCg%3D%3D&run=true):

```
"1254" "1342" M p    # => [1 2]
"1234" "1111" M p    # => [1 0]
"5441" "1234" M p    # => [0 2]
"5441" "4531" M p    # => [1 2]
"5441" "4441" M p    # => [3 0]
"5441" "5441" M p    # => [4 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

### GolfScript (48 chars)

```
{[\]:&zip{1/~=},,.~)10,{{''+-,~5+}+&%.~>=+}/}:E;
```

`E` here stands for `eval`. I take a similar approach to Knuth's definition of the number of white pegs by calculating `sum_{i=0}^{9} min(count(secret, i), count(guess, i))`.

[Online demo](http://golfscript.apphb.com/?c=e1tcXTomemlwezEvfj19LCwufikxMCx7eycnKy0sfjUrfSsmJS5%2BPj0rfS99OkU7Cgo7WwonMTI1NCcgJzEzNDInCSMgMSAyCicxMjM0JyAnMTExMScJIyAxIDAKJzU0NDEnICcxMjM0JwkjIDAgMgonNTQ0MScgJzQ1MzEnCSMgMSAyCic1NDQxJyAnNDQ0MScJIyAzIDAKJzU0NDEnICc1NDQxJwkjIDQgMAonMDAxMScgJzExMDAnCSMgMCA0Cl0yL3t%2BRV1wfS8%3D)

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 17 bytes

```
=s,4Y2@G!=s]Xlsy-
```

[Try it online](https://matl.suever.net/?code=%3Ds%2C4Y2%40G%21%3Ds%5DXlsy-&inputs=%271444%27%0A%274241%27&version=22.4.0) ([Tested multiple inputs with this](https://tio.run/##y00syfmfkKlQkldnrxerYBjho5CpYBTh89@2WMck0sgh0EfRtjg2Iqe4Uve/uq6urnqEi0JUhUJI7H91QyNTE3UudUNjEyMQZWQM5gEBkDI1MTFECEJ5JqbGSHImEMoUhVIHAA))

**Explanation**:

(For white pegs, Knuth's definition [as mentioned by Peter Taylor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/12496/8774) is used: `sum_{i=0}^{9} min(count(secret, i), count(guess, i))`)

```
=         % check which digits are equal
s         % sum of 1s is the number of red pegs
,         % do twice
  4Y2     % predefined literal: '0':'9'
  @G      % get the next input
  !=      % broadcast equality check
  s       % sum to get the count of each digit in the input
]         % end
Xl        % elementwise minimum
s         % sum
y-        % subtract the number of red pegs
          % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - 93

I'm pretty sure this is right. But a few example input/outputs in the question would help.

```
def m(S,G):
 R = [(s,g) for s,g in zip(S,G) if s!=g];S,G=zip(*R);W=set(S)&set(G);return 4-len(R),len(W)
```

And calling it gives:

```
print m('1234','1231') 
>>> (3, 0)
print m('1234','1230') 
>>> (3, 0)
print m('1234','1243') 
>>> (2, 2)
print m('1234','4312') 
>>> (0, 4)
print m("0123","0131") 
>>> (2, 1)
print m("0123","0132") 
>>> (2, 2)
print m("0123","0123") 
>>> (4, 0)
print m("0123","4131") 
>>> (1, 1)
```

Comment: The use of `set` makes me suspect that it will give a wrong answer for `m("0011", "1100")` (should be `(0,4)`).

Comment: @PeterTaylor Probably, but the rules seemed really poorly defined. But I'll change my anaswer if its wrong.

Comment: Knuth himself says that the rule for the number of white pegs "is somewhat difficult to state precisely and unambiguously, and the manufacturers have *not* succeeded in doing so on the directions they furnish with the game".

Answer (score 0):

Here's a first draft in PowerShell: `168` characters.

```
function Test-Mastermind{param([char[]]$s,[char[]]$g)
4-($p=0..3|?{$s[$_]-ne$g[$_]}).Count
($p|%{$i=$_;$p|?{$s[$i]-eq$g[$_]-and0-ne$s[$i]}|%{($s[$i]=$g[$_]=0)}}).Count}
```

For the sake of illumination:

```
function Test-Mastermind {
    param([char[]]$s,[char[]]$g)
    4 - ($p = 0..3|?{ $s[$_] -ne $g[$_] }).count # count same  characters
    ( $p | % { $i = $_                           # ForEach $i in $p (char in secret)
        $p | ? {                                 # ForEach $_ in $p (char in guess) 
            $s[$i] -eq $g[$_] -and 0 -ne $s[$i]  # If they match and aren't 0
         } | % { ($s[$i]=$g[$_]=0) }             # 0 them out, output something we can count
    } ).Count
}
```

Comment: Zeroes are allowed, so "0" shouldn't be the padding character.